# Flipping to the next page of a PDF

Tags: iphone, pdf, xamarin.ios

I found a great article for MonoTouch showing how to render the first page of a PDF as an image and now I want to to be able to allow the reader to access a second page.

Being completely new to ios and MonoTouch I have no idea how to add code to finger-swipe to the next page.  Can anyone offer any help on how swiping through images generated at runtime might be achieved?

Comment: Downvoted for domain squatter link.

Comment: Question updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just finished a scrollview compatible swipe gesture recognizer [here](http://code.devcentral.com.au/pdflinks). It's part of a larger project to allow the link annotations in the PDF to be clickable and launch safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIGestureRecognizer to do this, you do this by calling:

```
 var myRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer ();
 myRecognizer.AddTarget (delegate {
    Console.WriteLine ("Swiped!");
 };
 myView.AddGestureRecognizer (myRecognizer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand the link you provide but I hope my simple code may help to you`UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizerleft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeGestureRecognizerleft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeGestureRecognizerleft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeGestureRecognizerleft.delegate = self;
    [defaultPanGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGestureRecognizerleft];
    [defaultPinchGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGestureRecognizerleft];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizerleft];
    [swipeGestureRecognizerleft release];`

In the above i am  using UISwipeGestureRecognizer object to provide swipe functionality. In didswipe use to increase page number from that you call the CATiled layer part.